# django-registration - new user to a specific group

Tags: django, registration, django-registration

I'm using (and learning) Django on my newest product, and I just installed and started using [django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/) app to allow my users to auto-register themselves.

Everything's working good, but I'm thinking about assigning every new user to a specific group (already created), so I can "separate" the admins from the normal users.

How can I do this? The documentation about this app is awful, IMO.

I didn't create any model or configuration to start using the django-registration app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start, I'm not an expert at d-r (django-registration) and actually only checked it out because you mentioned it in your question. So, if anyone else has a better answer please submit it. Anyway, here it goes.

I noticed that the way users (or "profiles" as d-r calls them) are created is found in the create_inactive_user function located in registration.models.RegistrationManager. So, in this function after:

```
new_user.is_active = False
new_user.save()
```

You could add something like:

```
default_group = Group.objects.get(name=WHATEVER_THE_GROUP_NAME_IS)
user_group, is_created = UserGroup.get_or_create(user=new_user)
user_group.group = default_group
#user_group.groups.add(default_group)   # Django ver. 1.7+
user_group.save()
```

You could probably do without the get_or_create as I don't think you can create more than one user with the same username, but I would rather be safe than sorry.

This method will cause you to edit the d-r files (which may not be the best thing to do) along with hardcoding certain things (such as the default group name), but it should be a good stepping off point.

PS. the default group name could be a variable located in the settings.py file, which would make it more accessible and pretty. Example:

```
settings.py:
DEFAULT_GROUP_NAME = 'YOUR GROUP NAME'

registration/models.py:
default_group = Group.objects.get(name=settings.DEFAULT_GROUP_NAME)
```

Anyway, hope that helps.

Comment: Also, if you aren't using the actual permission's table (or your own) and you only need to differentiate between users and admins, then you could also use the is_staff and is_superuser fields in the User model.

Comment: That's a really good answer but I'll wait other replies since I don't want to change anything inside d-r code (it's outside my project)

Comment: @TiuTalk true it's outside your project but if you are using virtualenv then modifying installed packages for a single project shouldn't be too much of an issue. For me I changed the file in ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/registration which was local to my given django project.

Comment: At least as of d-r 0.8, you could also take the backend approach. Make your own backend by duplicating the backend you're already using (whether that's 'default' or 'simple'). Move it out of the d-r packages directory to somewhere in your project. Then modify the register() function as needed without feeling like you're breaking things, since this is your own backend now.

Comment: @BryceSiedschlaw: I found that user_group 'has no attribute 'group' '. The right attribute is 'groups', at least in Django 1.7! So the line is now `user_group.groups.add(default_group)` ! Thanks for the tip anyway! Works now for me!

Answer (score 4):

I ended up making a fork for this, as this was driving me crazy.

https://github.com/kcunning/django-registration

Basically, add the following to your settings.py file:

REGISTRATION_DEFAULT_GROUP_NAME="Groupname"

Any user added through the registration module will be given that group upon creation.

Comment: this is crazy! How something so simple can be so difficult

Answer (score 0):

django-registration-redux has custom signals that can be used to assign registered user to a specific group. "user_registered" signal can be used for this purpose. Please refer to [django-registration-redux documentation](https://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signals.html)

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group


def user_created(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    group = Group.objects.get(name='Kurum') 
    group.user_set.add(user)
    user.save()


from registration.signals import user_registered
user_registered.connect(user_created)
```